# How to get kubernetes pod network CIDR

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I have a running k8s cluster initialized with `kubeadm`.

On initialization, I did not pass the option `--pod-network-cidr`

How do I get the CIDR of the pod network

I tried

- Looking at the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` which seems to be the manifest for kube-apiserver used by `kubeadm` but that information is not included
- Looking at the [`kubeadm` document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/) but I couldn't find a default value

Answer (score 27):

This command will give you the pod CIDR addresses for each of the nodes in your cluster.

`kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.podCIDR}'`

Comment: It's blank in my case `"spec": {},`

Comment: It was blank in my case too earlier but passing --pod-network-cidr during kubeadm reinitialisation resolved this

Answer (score 13):

This will show pod network CIDR which used by `kube-proxy`

```
kubectl cluster-info dump | grep -m 1 cluster-cidr
```

Comment: This returns nothing in my case.

Answer (score 9):

my version of `kubeadm` is 1.22 and the command to view defaults is `kubeadm config print init-defaults`, towards the bottom:

```
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that worked for me (K8s v. 1.24.0) - thank you.

Comment: For me too, the only answer that works! Thanks!

Comment: Same for me too

Comment: WARNING, I wanna put emphasis on the fact that this is NOT your actually configured cidr range for the cluster but only what `kubeadm init` defaults too. This works for OP because they didn't specify a pod cidr, but ONLY works in this case !

Answer (score 4):

The `--cluster-cidr` / `--pod-network-cidr` is fed to `kube-controller-manager` config.

You can simply do `ps -ef | grep "cluster-cidr"` to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's in file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`

```
# sudo grep cidr /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-*
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --node-cidr-mask-size=24
```

Answer (score 1):

With kubeadm

`kubeadm config view | grep Subnet`

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Could you explain what is the difference with the other commands that were provided in the other answer and could you add an example of the output of this command?

Comment: I get invalid subcommand: "view"  kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.9", GitCommit:"6df4433e288edc9c40c2e344eb336f63fad45cd2",

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options (combining the existing answers and adding option for Calico, including example ouput):

**Option 1**: Run this command On the master node (also applicable when running for example microk8s on Ubuntu)

- **kubeadm config view | grep Subnet**

example output from local 3 node cluster, master node

```
podSubnet: 172.16.0.0/16
serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
```

**Option 2**: Run this command on the master node:

- **ps -ef | grep cluster-cidr**

example output from local machine running microk8s

```
vincent   6841 27089  0 09:52 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cluster-cidr
root      7053     1  0 feb12 ?        00:00:14 /snap/microk8s/1173/kube-proxy --kubeconfig=/var/snap/microk8s/1173/credentials/proxy.config --cluster-cidr=10.152.183.0/24 --healthz-bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

**Option 3**: Run this command on the master node:

- **sudo grep cidr /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-***

Example output of same master node:

```
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --cluster-cidr=172.16.0.0/16
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml:    - --node-cidr-mask-size=24
```

If you run Calico you have the option to use calicoctl:

https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/usage/calicoctl/install

This documentation shows how to show and also change the cidr:
https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/usage/changing-ip-pools

**Option 4** (Calico): Run this command to view the cidr:

- **CALICO_KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config DATASTORE_TYPE=kubernetes calicoctl get ippool -o wide**

Example output for the same cluster (works from any place that has the proper kubectl config and connection to the cluster):

```
NAME                  CIDR            NAT    IPIPMODE   DISABLED   SELECTOR   
default-ipv4-ippool   172.16.0.0/16   true   Always     false      all()
```

Depending on your network option, you may have other options which are hopefully documented in the respective documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To get Service IP range - i.e. IP's assigned to ClusterIP, the command is:

- `ps -aux | grep kube-apiserver | grep service-cluster-ip-range` (you can run this on master node)
- `cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml | grep service-cluster-ip-range`

To find the Pod network range, when you have defined your cluster using kubeadm 1.22 and used weave as your networking addon:
first find the weave pod name using

`kubectl get pod -n kube-system | grep weave`

Copy any one name out of the three pod names.

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs <<weave-net-podname-from-above-step>> -c weave | grep ipalloc-range
```

you will find either default i.e. 10.32.0.0/12 or whatever range you assigned during kubeadm init